# How to contain within relative parent container an absolute child

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-position, absolute

Is there a way to let the relative parent height container to grow according to his absolute child?

https://codepen.io/daniele-acquaviva/pen/JzpzxG

```css
.relative-parent {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.absolute-child {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative-parent">
  <p> Parent div content </p>
  <div class="absolute-child">
    <p> child </p>
    <p> child </p>
    <p> child </p>
    <p> child </p>
    <p> child </p>
    <p> child </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `position: absolute;` for childs, they are not take into account into parent content.

According to the w3schools documentation : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

> The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element

---

**EDIT :**
This can be achieved with javascript, see here https://codepen.io/tmacpolo/pen/ywvWbb

**EDIT2 :**
Added the MutationObserver to adjust the height of the parent when the child's height changes
https://codepen.io/tmacpolo/pen/ywvWbb

Comment: i know but i would like to find a solution to that if it is possible in css. Otherwise maybe with javascript changing the relative-parent container height to the absolute-child one, but how would i know when to update the relative-parent container height when the absolute-child's is changing.?

Comment: If you want the parent height match the childs one, you don't have to use absolute for your childs. 
Is mandatory for you to set the position to absolute ?

Comment: Yes i need the child container to overlap the parent, but doing that the folllowing web-site content doesn't have any distance from the child absolute container so the folllowing web-site content (other divs for example) is overlapped as well.

Comment: I finally succeeded to match the size of the parent div to the size of the child div with javascript. See here : https://codepen.io/tmacpolo/pen/ywvWbb

Comment: Perfect ! I had it into my answer :)

Comment: Even if i would like to add an event listerner that update the parent height only when the child height changes.

Comment: I think this can be done using the  MutationObserver in js

Comment: Yes, It works with MutationObserver => codepen.io/tmacpolo/pen/ywvWbb

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible actually because of how absolute works as it is out of flow from the layout. Only way to avoid collapsing is giving force height to its parent element.

Comment: Maybe with javascript changing the relative-parent container height to the absolute-child one, but how would i know when to update the relative-parent container height when the absolute-child's is changing.?

Comment: With jquery hieght() and on change to the child div this can be done. 

Ref: 1) http://api.jquery.com/height/
and 

$(document).on('change', 'child-div', function() {
  // Does some stuff and logs the event to the console
});
Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for helping but at the moment i'm not considering to use jquery, so i would prefer to do it with plain javaScript